# Validation using Ajax call not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am new to Ajax and Jquery.I have a form where there is a `DepositAccountNumberId` text box and its value is stored in a Hidden Field for Validation.

`OnBlur` event of DepositAccountNumberId TextBox should give a bootbox `alert ("This Account Number has been Suspended")`. I have posted the code below:

**Javascript Function to CheckAccountSuspension()**

```js
var exist = true;

    function checkAccountSuspension() {
        var accountNumberId = $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val();

      //  alert(accountNumberId);
        if (accountNumberId == "") {
            //
        } else {
            try {
                var url = '/WebMethods/AccountDetails.asmx/IsAccountSuspended';
               
                var d = { accountNumberId: accountNumberId };
                //var jqXhr = $.post(url, d);
                //jqXhr.done(function(data) {
                $.post(url, d, function (data) {

                    if (data) {
                        var ret = data.d;
                        if (ret) {
                            $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val(accountNumberId);
                            exist = true;
                        } else {
                            $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val('');
                            bootbox.alert("This Account Has been Suspended");
                            exist = false;
                        }
                    }

                }).fail(function() {
                    $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val('');
                });


            } catch (e) {
                bootbox.alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        }
```

**Web Method**

```
  [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public bool IsAccountSuspended(string accountNumberId)
    {
        int officeId = OfficeId;
        return BusinessLayer.Transactions.Transactions.IsAccountSuspended(officeId, accountNumberId.ToLong());
    }
```

**IsAccountSuspended in Business Layer**

```
public static bool IsAccountSuspended(int officeId, long accountNumberId)
    {
        if (accountNumberId <= 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return DatabaseLayer.Transactions.Transactions.IsAccountSuspended(officeId,accountNumberId);
    }
```

**IsAccountSuspended in Database Layer**

```
public static bool IsAccountSuspended(int officeId, long accountNumberId)
    {

        if (accountNumberId <= 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var sql = "SELECT * FROM deposit.is_suspended(@AccountNumberId::bigint);";
        using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumberId", accountNumberId);
            using (var table = DBOperations.GetDataTable(command))
            {
                if (table.Rows.Count >= 1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }


    }
```

The Validation does not work.The ajax is not called to check if the account is suspended.Help Please.

Comment: I am still learning jquery and ajax.Dont i need Ajaxpost()?

Comment: is Folder webmethod at the root

Comment: @tariq Yes sir.It is at the root.

Comment: @OLDMONK there is no such method as `ajaxPost` in `jQuery`, you should use [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) or [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to send requests.

Comment: @OLDMONK Check my edit now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is How it worked.

Like some of the experts above said about the use of postAjax and $.post.
As everywhere in the project it was used as postAjax by previous developers here.
I was actually passing a null value again in the hidden field.
This code worked.

```js
  var exist = true;

        function checkAccountSuspension() {
            var accountNumberId = $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val();
            if (accountNumberId == "") {
                //
            } else {
                try {
                    var url = '/WebMethods/AccountDetails.asmx/IsAccountSuspended';
                    var d = { accountNumberId: accountNumberId };
                    //$.post(url, d, function (data) {
                    var jqXhr = ajaxPost(url, d, true);
                    jqXhr.done(function (data) {
                        var ret = data.d;
                        if (!ret) {
                            $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val(accountNumberId);
                            exist = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            //$('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val('');
                            //  bootbox.alert("<b class='text-red'>Suspended Account</b> <br/>This Account has been Suspended.");
                            swal({
                                title: "Suspended Account!",
                                text: "This Account is Suspended",
                                type: "error",
                                confirmButtonText: "OK",
                                imageSize: "20x20"
                            });
                            exist = false;
                            resetAllInputs();
                        }
                    }).fail(function (ex) {
                        bootbox.alert("Requested process fail to execute");
                        //$('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val('');
                    });
                }
                catch (e) {
                    bootbox.alert('Error: ' + e);
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$.post` method:

```
var exist = true;

function checkAccountSuspension() {
    var accountNumberId = $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val();

    //  alert(accountNumberId);
    if (accountNumberId == "") {
        //
    } else {
        try {
            var url = '/WebMethods/AccountDetails.asmx/IsAccountSuspended';

            var d = {accountNumberId: accountNumberId};
            var jqXhr = $.post(url, d);
            jqXhr.done(function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    var ret = data.d;
                    if (ret) {
                        $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val(accountNumberId);
                        exist = true;
                    } else {
                        $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val('');
                        bootbox.alert("This Account Has been Suspended");
                        exist = false;
                    }
                }

            }).fail(function () {
                $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val('');
            });

        } catch (e) {
            bootbox.alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    }
}


$('#DepositAccountNumberTextBox').on('blur', function () {
    checkAccountSuspension();
});
```

Comment: @OLDMONK and network tab? does request is being sent?

Comment: called isnt reaching the asmx..and cant see any request being sent

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method like ajaxPost in JQuery. Use $.Post at its place.

```
try {
       var url = '/WebMethods/AccountDetails.asmx/IsAccountSuspended';
       var d = { accountNumberId: accountNumberId };
       $.post(url,d,function(data){
          if (data) {
             var ret = data.d;
             if (ret) {
                $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val(accountNumberId);
                exist = true;
             }
             else {
                $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val('');
                bootbox.alert("This Account Has been Suspended");
                exist = false;
             }
          }
      }).error(function() { 
          $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val('');
      })
    } 
    catch (e) {
        bootbox.alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
```

Comment: Should i use this    var jqXhr =  $.post(url,d,function(data)

Comment: You can modify it your way a bit. Yes use it at it's place and remove jqhxr.done

Comment: whatever you are doing inside jqhxr, you can do inside callback function ie the last parameter of $.post

Comment: Does it work now..? place a breakpoint at the method in the asmx and see if its called

Comment: Press f12 on the browser , after blur check for any javascript errors

Comment: Cant find any errors sir..I think i have problem with the DepositAccntNumIdHiddenField Sir..because the hiddenfield of the depositaccounttextbox is storing the accountnumber and not accountnumberid..how do i make hiddenfieldstore accountnumberid and not accountnumber?

Comment: un comment this alert //  alert(accountNumberId); and check what is alerted is correct or not

Comment: Pages keeps loading with the alert window sir..cant alert the value

Comment: Is the webmethod called now... ?